# Javascript regex to extract count at end of file

Tags: javascript, regex

I am fairly new to regex and am in need of some help.

The end goal is to capture the final sequence of numbers before the period in a file name. For example, I want to extract the '04' from 'test687.09ew0_d04.jpg'. Another example would be the '787' from '039lksdkl3200dj787.jpg'.

This is my regex so far:

```
/([0-9]+)(?:\.[\s\S]+)$/
```

My understanding is that the `([0-9]+)` matches any number of digits 1 through 9.

The `(?:\.[\s\S]+)` specifies that the digits must be followed by a dot and any number of characters, the `?:` marking that it should not be captured, but used to match.

The `$` at the end is meant to only match if the requirements are at the end of the string and nowhere else.

However, it is not working. The non-capture groups are returned in my matches, and the regex is not requiring that the match be at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to extract the '04' from 'test687.09ew0_d04.jpg'.

The solution using `String.prototype.match()` function:

```js
var getLastDigits = function(str){
    var m = str.match(/(\d+)\.\w+$/);
    return m[1];
};

console.log(getLastDigits('test687.09ew0_d04.jpg'));
console.log(getLastDigits('039lksdkl3200dj787.jpg'));
```

Comment: This worked great! However, I do wonder why m[0] returns the entire ending piece. And would you mind showing me why mine didn't work?

Comment: @HunterS, `m[0]` is always contains the full match. All next indexes will point to the respective capturing groups. Non-capturing group `(?:\.[\s\S]+)$` won't work in such case(it can not bind non-capturing group contents with the end of the string `(?:..)` <> `$`)

Comment: Oh! Well that seems strange to me! Thanks for the answer!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) such as `[^.]` to match all the non-`.` characters at the end of the file name, `[^.]+$`.

Then match the literal `.` character, `\.`, and capture the previous digits, `(\d+)`.

```
(\d+)\.[^.]+$
```

The expression above would capture `04` in the string `test687.09ew0_d04.jpg` - [example here](https://regex101.com/r/hFcRYP/1).

Comment: This one worked great as well! What is the difference between this and RomanPerekhrest's answer? I'm pretty sure the `\w` would cover everything at the end of a file name. Unless there is something I missed?

Comment: @HunterS `\w` is a shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, that is letters (small and caps) plus underscore.

Comment: Well that's neat! Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: @HunterS Plus numbers too. I forgot them in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var regex = /(\d+)\.[^\.]*$/;



function check(){
  var str = prompt("Filename example: ");
  var m = str.match(regex);
  if(m && m[1])
    alert("Here you go: " + m[1]);
  else
    alert("Nothing matched!");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="check()">TRY</button>
```